# Fill null columns between not null columns with default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null

I am trying to fill all `NULL` columns between specified columns.

My Table:

[image: Table]

I want to fill every column which is `NULL` if a higher level has a value in it.

For example:

- Row with ID 1 Level3 should have a default value ('def')
- Row with ID 2 is ok. Last filled Column is level4 and no column after that has a value in it.
- Row with ID 3 Level5, Level6, Level7, Level8, Level9 should have a default value ('def')
- Row with ID 4 Level4, Level5, Level6, Level8, Level9 should have a default value ('def')

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78d09a)

Comment: What if there's a value in `Level1`, `Level2`  and `Level5` and `Level7`? Should `Level6` be updated with a default value also?

Comment: no only NULL Columns.

Comment: But in my example `Level6` has no value.

Comment: sorry my fault. Yes every column which has NULL and has a higher column with a value in it. Ive edited my post ;-)

Comment: See this one based on@cha 's answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/032ba/2/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I could think of:

```
update #Levels
set 
level1 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(level2, level3, level4, level5, level6, level7, level8, level9, level10) IS NULL THEN level1 ELSE ISNULL(level1, 'def') END,
level2 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(level3, level4, level5, level6, level7, level8, level9, level10) IS NULL THEN level2 ELSE ISNULL(level2, 'def') END,
level3 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(level4, level5, level6, level7, level8, level9, level10) IS NULL THEN level3 ELSE ISNULL(level3, 'def') END,
level4 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(level5, level6, level7, level8, level9, level10) IS NULL THEN level4 ELSE ISNULL(level4, 'def') END,
level5 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(level6, level7, level8, level9, level10) IS NULL THEN level5 ELSE ISNULL(level5, 'def') END,
level6 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(level7, level8, level9, level10) IS NULL THEN level6 ELSE ISNULL(level6, 'def') END,
level7 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(level8, level9, level10) IS NULL THEN level7 ELSE ISNULL(level7, 'def') END,
level8 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(level9, level10) IS NULL THEN level8 ELSE ISNULL(level8, 'def') END,
level9 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(level10, null) IS NULL THEN level9 ELSE ISNULL(level9, 'def') END
```

Looks messy, but does the job

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/032ba/2/0a)

Comment: Replace the `ELSE` part with `ISNULL(<column>, 'def')` and you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks @FelixPamittan. That was the missing link

Comment: You could also add a `WHERE Level1 IS NULL OR Level2 IS NULL ..`. At least it wouldn't have to update all rows with the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks :-) My first attempts where all to complicated.. :-)